# Using Profile 2 with Entity Reference--How to display the user name and not the "Profile Name"

Tags: users

I've reviewed the threads similar to this, and can't seem to find a definitive answer. I have a Content Type in Drupal 7 where I want to be able to associate multiple users to a content item. For example, I have a "Music Ensemble" content type, and I want the ensemble leader to be able to select all of their ensemble members from the list of user profiles.

I've been through all the steps to configure a view with the Entity Reference Widget, and add / configure the Entity Reference field on my content type. When I go to create a content item, the View loads, displays the correct profile fields and allows me to select users.

However, when I submit the view form and return to the content UI, I get the following:

[image: ensemble widget]

The "Main profile" text is displayed for every member I select. What I really want to display on the content item is the user's name from their profile.

I can't seem to find a way to configure around this. Is this simply a limitation of the Entity Reference / Profile 2 relationship, or is there something I'm missing that could solve this? I can figure things out on the front-end display with Views, but this is rather challenging for someone unfamiliar with content authoring (which most of my authors are).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Entity View Modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) to create a User view mode, and then set the fields for display on that view mode. Then select the view mode in the field formatter for the Entity Reference field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this addresses the front-end display issue, which I've already solved. I'm trying to address the issue on the content authoring form. 

In case anyone is following along, I've also tried addressing the issue with [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel). No joy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. What is the "content UI"?

Comment: The form that the content author uses to enter content into Drupal. The end user display is fixable through configuration. I'm trying to make it easier for someone creating a new content item to see what items have been selected during the authoring process.